The loading message is only displayed after adding a 1ms delay
I have a very simple loading message:
<div v-show="isLoading" class="preloader">Loading...</div>

data() {
  return {
    isLoading: false
  }
},

In a child component method that adds markers to a map using the Google Maps API, I'm changing the attribute value using $emit:
methods: {
  async initMarkers() {
    this.$emit('loading', true)
    const map = this.map
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary('marker')

    try {
      this.members.map((member) => {
        const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map,
          title: member.ttl,
          position: {
            lat: parseFloat(member.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(member.lng)
          }
        })

        this.markers.push(marker)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading marker library', error)
    } finally {
      this.$emit('loading', false)
    }
  },
}

The process takes about 2 seconds to complete, but the loading message is not being displayed. It only appears when I add a delay of at least 1ms.
this.$emit('loading', true)
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1))
try{

I would like to understand why this delay is necessary and if it is considered bad practice.

What's going on in ...? It needs to return to the event loop to allow the page to render. If it blocks the UI, nothing will change.

This is the reason why nextTick exists. Yes. it's a bad practice to put arbitrary timeouts in your code. It's unclear if it's necessary.  The reason it might be necessary is that “...” is a blocking operation, which is bad and should generally be avoided. Its unknown if this is the case here, could be XY problem

Also it is possible that you element is loading immediately and something else is take the process longer to 2 sec. Check network tap in inspection for time.

@Barmar, I updated the code and give more details about the method.

Are you sure that await google.maps.importLibrary takes 2 secs to load? Please add console logs after emitting the loading event to estimate the processing time. Somehow, I think, the loading status is ok and it happens quite fast that the UI won't get updated. Can you provide a reproducible online playground?

@Raeisi I used performance.now() and the method is taking around 1.5 secs. Does this explain why the loading message is not showing?
